# Accessing files using Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to make a DrRacket program that can copy all of the files from a given directory (taking it off of a USB Camera (when it's plugged in it's seen as a mass storage device)) and paste them into a folder on my computer's hard drive.  For whatever reason I'm unable to figure out DrRacket's implementation of a path on the computer (ie. for the Desktop on a Windows Machine it would be: `C:\Users\Mike\Desktop`) I read the help desk and still can't figure this out.  Any suggestions as to where I should look to clear up my confusion? I think the function call that I'll need to implement this idea is:

```
(copy-directory/files src dst)
```

After I figure that out I'm going to work on a GUI for it so it operates at the click of a button.

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for the content about [paths](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pathutils.html).  You can create a path using [build-path](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._build-path%29%29).  A lot of the path-manipulating functions, though, can take strings as well.  So you should be able to say something like:

```
#lang racket
(copy-directory/files "C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\..." ...)
```

with the *...* replaced appropriately.

Comment: If you're wondering why is Racket making this so complicated, the answer is to give you a cross-platform benefit: A way to characterize pathanmes without hardcoding \ or /, for example. However if you don't want that benefit, and don't mind hardcoding to one platform, you can use strings. Just remember that \ is an escape character in a string literal (just like in C/C++), so you'll need to use \\ as dyoo showed.